# Cognos Report Studio YYYYMM formatting date in report

Tags: report, cognos

I have SQL which generates date output like this:

**YYYYMM: 201503

reportDate: "March 2015"**

In report I need something to look like 'reportDate' type.

Does anyone know how to set up this thing to be human readable type?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't format your date in your SQL. Have your query return a date, and then you can format it however you want in Cognos.

Comment: Hi Andrew, what I am doing is I have few fields from SQL: Year and Month, I am adding them together with this: minimum ([Test DB2 Source].[New Query Subject1].[YEAR]*100+[Test DB2 Source].[New Query Subject1].[MONTH]) as I need minimum value from SQL, then 201503 data is like this, but eventually I need to look like March 2015

Comment: Okay, in that case build strings for each part of the date, and then cast that as a date.  So something like `CAST ([Test DB2 Source].[New Query Subject1].[YEAR]*100 as char(4)) || '-' || ...`, and just add `'-01'` to the end of it, so you end up with '2015-03-01'.  Then you can cast that as a date, and format it in Cognos.

Comment: Thanks for help, but what I get now is something like that:
201412-01 and after I say format as a date it's still shows like that. :/

Comment: You're missing a hyphen between your year and month.

Comment: How to insert - between YYYYMM to look like YYYY-MM and then add '-01'

Comment: SUBSTR([YearMonthVar], 1, 4) || '-' || substr([YearMonthVar], 5, 2)